# I'm getting "" is a required value on Magento checkout page

Tags: checkout, error, html, form-validation

On Magento V1.9 on the checkout page (onepage). When filling out the billing page and clicking submit. I get this error:

> "" is a required value
>
> "" is a required value

I am lead to believe that these are blank inputs/values. I have checked the html code for any such blank values. I have tried to run a query in the database for example:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    eav_attribute 
WHERE 
    frontend_label LIKE '%""%' AND 
    entity_type_id IN (
        SELECT 
            entity_type_id 
        FROM 
            eav_entity_type 
        WHERE 
            entity_type_code = 'customer_address'
     )
```

I have spent 5 days trying to diagnose this issue. Your expert advice would be truly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query you are using is probably not going to actually show you the problem. What is almost certainly happening is that you have a custom form which does not have an input for one or more reqiured feilds. The message may well be a result of a blank label but the query that your looking for there is actually asking for feilds which contain "" in it.

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE is_required=1 AND entity_type_id IN (
        SELECT 
            entity_type_id 
        FROM 
            eav_entity_type 
        WHERE 
            entity_type_code = 'customer_address'
     );
```

I've modified it to replace the query for the label with required feilds. This should give you a number of feilds which are marked as required, then you can use this to compare against the form and see which are missing.

Comment: John thank you very much for this. It has solved my issue. There was custom fields which I had compared and found that building was missing and a mds field which was missing too. My sleepless nights are over. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I found this extension which is can custom fields in checkout page 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-step-checkout-37-28858.html

You can manage fields by dragging and dropping them, even make it hidden or optional